# Mixins and placeholder selector scope - Styles not being applied to current selector

Tags: sass

I'm writing a mixin for adding a graphical effect to the corner of a box:

[image: Screenshot example of graphical effect]

The mixin will accept a corner position (tl, tr, bl, br), size, and colors:

```
@mixin notch($notch-location, $size, $foreground-color, $background-color) {
    %top--left {
        @extend %notch;

        &:before {
            top: 0; left: 0;
            border-width: $size $size 0 0;
        }
    }

    // etc ...

    %notch {
        position: relative;

        &:before {
            @extend .pel;

            position: absolute;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: $foreground-color $background-color;
        }
    }

    @if $notch-location == top-left {
        @extend %top--left;
    }

    // etc ...
}
```

I then use the mixin on a selector, for example:

```
a {
    @include notch(top-left, 24px, $color-brand, #fff);
}
```

Unfortunately the resulting CSS isn't what I'm expecting:

```
.menu.collapsed .nav .nav--current a a:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-width: 24px 24px 0 0;
}
.menu.collapsed .nav .nav--current a a {
  position: relative;
}
.menu.collapsed .nav .nav--current a a:before {
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ec5b25 white;
}
```

---

**Example:**

- [SCSS (jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/8Hb8Z/)
- [Compiled CSS (jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/vcbjf/)

---

As you can see, the styles added via the mixin are being qualified with an extra `a`. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output is exactly as I would expect because of the nature of extends.  The `%notch` class belongs to the parent selector (`a` in your case).  If you change it to `.notch` instead, it becomes obvious.

Extend classes are not ephemeral.  It's a good idea to avoid defining them within a mixin you plan on reusing.  Doing so will cause the class to be generated each time you invoke the mixin, causing duplication of code all over the place (which you probably don't want).

```
%notch {
    position: relative;

    &:before {
        @extend .pel;

        position: absolute;
        border-style: solid;
    }
}

@mixin notch($notch-location, $size, $foreground-color, $background-color) {
    @extend %notch;
    border-color: $foreground-color $background-color;

    &:before {
        @if $notch-location == top-left {
            top: 0; left: 0;
            border-width: $size $size 0 0;
        } @else if $notch-location == top-right {
            top: 0; right: 0;
            border-width: $size 0 0 $size;
        } @else if $notch-location == bottom-left {
            bottom: 0; left: 0;
            border-width: 0 $size $size 0;
        } @else {
            bottom: 0; right: 0;
            border-width: 0 0 $size $size;
        }
    }
}

a {
    display: block;
    width: 100px; height: 100px;
    background: #0f0;

    @include notch(top-left, 24px, #0f0, #0f0);
}
```

It's also worth noting that extends aren't always the best choice, they can cause the code to be larger than it would be if you'd simply duplicated the code due to repeating the selector.

Comment: Thanks! Visualising the placeholder selectors as normal classes was a big help.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have messed up your code structure.

I'm not sure why this extra `a` appears, but when i refactor your code to have reasonable structure, the problem disappears:

```
$color-brand: pink;

%notch {
    position: relative;

    &:before {
        @extend .pel !optional;

        position: absolute;
        border-style: solid;
    }
}

%top--left {
    @extend %notch;

    &:before {
        top: 0; left: 0;
    }
}

@mixin notch($notch-location, $size, $foreground-color, $background-color) {

    border-color: $foreground-color $background-color;

    @if $notch-location == top-left {
        @extend %top--left;
        border-width: $size $size 0 0;
    }
    // etc ...
}


a {
    @include notch(top-left, 24px, $color-brand, #fff);
}
```

Demo: http://sassbin.com/gist/6019481/