# SASS: last item in list of arguments

Tags: list, arguments, sass

i was trying to make a mixin that gets arguments (that can be a variable list) and then after the last item of the list doesn't output a comma. this is the mixin so far:

```
   @mixin i-class($name...,$pua) {
      @if type-of($name) == "list" {
          @for $className from 1 through length($name) {
              .#{$classIcon}.#{$className}:before,
          } 
              { content: "\e#{$pua}";}
          }
      }
      @else {
          .#{$classPrefix}.#{$name}:before { 
            content: "\e#{$pua}";
          }
      }
    }
```

this would be the desired output if one parameter is passed like so:

```
@include i-class(someIcon,"000");

.icon.someIcon:before {
    content: "\e000";
}
```

and if multiple arguments were passed (a list), then the output would be like this:

```
@include i-class(someIcon,someIcon2,someIcon3,"001");

.icon.someIcon:before, .icon.someIcon2:before, .icon.someIcon3:before {
    content: "\e001";
}
```

i just don't know what to use to check if it's the last item in the list and then omit the comma. help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The catchall argument must be the last argument in a mixin.  It would be simpler to take advantage of lists to create the selector than to manually insert commas yourself:

```
@mixin i-class($pua, $name...) {
    $selector: ();

    @each $className in $name {
        $selector: append($selector, unquote('.#{$classIcon}.#{$className}:before'), comma);
    }

    #{$selector} {
        content: "\e#{$pua}";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@cimmanon's answer works fine, but if you want to avoid duplications you can try to use the placeholders. Like that:

```
$classPrefix: ".icon";
$i-class-stack: ();

@mixin i-class($pua, $names...) {
  // A stack is used to create a placeholder by `$pua`.
  @if not index($i-class-stack, $pua) {
    $i-class-stack: append($i-class-stack, $pua);
    %i-class-#{$pua} {
      content: "\e#{$pua}";
    }
  }
  @each $name in $names {
    #{$classPrefix}.#{$name}:before {
      @extend %i-class-#{$pua};
    }
  }
}

// First call to the mixin to generate a rule with `content: "\e001"`.
@include i-class("001", someIcon, someIcon2);

// Do stuff
.foobar {
  background-color: blue;
}

// Another call to the i-class mixin, but with a new value.
@include i-class("025", someIcon, someIcon2);

// Now, we add some new selectors to the first CSS rule
// (with `content: "\e001"`).
@include i-class("001", someIcon3, someIcon4);
```

See the output:

```
.icon.someIcon:before, .icon.someIcon2:before, .icon.someIcon3:before, .icon.someIcon4:before {
  content: "\e001";
}

.foobar {
  background-color: blue;
}

.icon.someIcon:before, .icon.someIcon2:before {
  content: "\e025";
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can use extends for this purpose as well, but defining the extend class within the mixin causes more harm than good:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17689735/mixins-and-placeholder-selector-scope-styles-not-being-applied-to-current-sele

Comment: Absolutely! This is why I use the variable $classPrefix instead of the parent selector, and each placeholder is reserved for use it programmatically.